# java regexp " [_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+ " what dose the "\\+"mean in it?

Tags: java

java regexp, what dose the "\+"mean in  " [_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+ "?
I know + means one or more than one, so what doese \+ mean?

Comment: A character within a character class denotes a literal character.

Comment: @supernova: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider bookmarking the our [Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference. In particular, check out the answers for [character classes:`[...]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1553171) and the list of online regex testers (in the bottom section) where you can try things out your self.

Comment: The only correct answer to this question is one character long.  Unfortunately, Stack Overflow won't let me post a single character answer.

Comment: @supernova The regexes were not showing correctly, I've edited you post to fix that. But you mentioned `\\+` in the question heading and `\\\+` in the question - that's inconsistent.

Comment: @0605002 - You seem to have changed the question completely.  Why?

Comment: @DavidWallace Not completely, I've just replaced some double-quotes with backticks. See mark-down comparison in edit history.

Comment: @0605002 Well, the question showed one backslash previously.  Now it shows three.  So you've made it into a different question.  That won't help supernova at all.  I think it would be best if you put the question back how it was.

Comment: @DavidWallace but supernova did type three backslashes in the question, but that was not appearing properly. You can try it easily: edit the question, type multiple backslashes (not in a code block) and see the preview. Seems that the SO editor also needs escaped backslashes, but in a weird way.

Comment: @0605002 Presumably, supernova typed the right number of backslashes to get his/her question appearing the way he/she wanted it.  You shouldn't go changing a question if (i) you are not the OP, and (ii) people have already started answering.  Please undo your vandalism.

Answer (score 1):

None of the special characters works like that within a character class (i.e. characters enclosed between `[` and `]`). The regex would literally match the characters `_`, `A` to `Z`, `a` to `z`, `0` to `9`, `-`, `\` and `+`.

As this is a java string, the `\` character needs to be escaped with another `\`.

**Edit:**

Just found out, backslashes need to be escaped within a character class. So, to match a `\`, it should be `\\`. Indeed `\` remains a special character within a character class, that's why we can use things like `\d`, `\w` within character classes.

The regex should be `[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+`. See [here](http://regex101.com/r/tQ8yW2).

Comment: Indeed. The original regex was written based on incorrect beliefs.

Comment: I've just tested this.  The regexp does not match a backslash - backslash is still special inside square brackets.  This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yeah, you're right. I've edited my post. However, the question was not showing the regex correctly.

Comment: I've removed my downvote, because at this point, it's anybody's guess what the question was actually meant to be.  I took it to mean two backslashes written in the literal, that is, one backslash in the actual regular expression - which means it wouldn't match backslash.  However, now that there are three backslashes in the question, who knows?

Comment: It simply means "\+" two distinct characters \ and + since one extra slash is for escape

Answer (score 0):

It is not a accepted regexp, if you want to try it out IDE shows an error
you can try this :

```
[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+]
```