# understanding this python regular expression re.compile(r'[ :]')

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am trying to understand python code which has this regular expression `re.compile(r'[ :]')`. I tried quite a few strings and couldnt find one. Can someone please give example where a text matches this pattern.

Comment: `[]` means "any character from between these brackets". So your expression will match any space or colon character.

Comment: The reference post links to [How to back reference "inner" selections ( () ) in a regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1553171) for character classes.

Comment: There are only two strings the pattern matches. `' '` and `':'`. Depending on how you *use* the pattern, those strings can be part of a larger string.

Answer (score 0):

The expression simply matches a single space or a single `:` (or rather, a string containing either). That’s it. `[…]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` matches any of the characters in the brackets. So `[ :]` will match one character that is either a space or a colon.

So these strings would have a match:

```
"Hello World"
"Field 1:"
etc...
```

These would not

```
"This_string_has_no_spaces_or_colons"
"100100101"
```

Edit:
For more info on regular expressions: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: I tried as the pattern r'[ :]'and Hello World as the test string in  http://pythex.org/ but it doesn't match.

Comment: This worked for me: http://tiny.cc/mnr1px