# Combing javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two replace methods called on a string, and I know they can be combined. I would like to know how to combine the two expressions, why, and maybe links to more information

```
var key = templateKey.replace(/:/g, '').replace(/\//g,'')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Dr. Google can give you lots of links for more information on regular expressions, but in this case you're just replacing either a colon (:) or a slash (/), so you could combine them using the OR (|) grouping:

```
/(:|\/)/
```

Comment: So much information on google for regex! It's been a real challenge for me to pick up. The "Or" operator and grouping is exactly the information I wanted to know! exp +50, regex lvl ++. The "more resources" request was in hopes someone had an idiots guide to regex basics laying around.

Comment: btw, ateich's answer is also correct (it gets an upvote from me).

Answer (score 1):

```
var key = templateKey.replace(/[:\/]/g, '');
```

Comment: Can i get some explanation for this expression?

Comment: @TheodoreEnderby read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545751/how-to-back-reference-inner-selections-in-a-regular-expression/1553171#1553171)