# Remove all characters with ascii codes 32 - 47 and some more from string

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove all characters with ascii codes 32 - 47 and some more from string. Exactly `!"#$%&'()*+,-./\~`.

I tried:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\\~/', '', $string);
```

But it returned false. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You should really read about [**character classes**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545751/how-to-back-reference-inner-selections-in-a-regular-expression/1553171#1553171, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801630/what-is-the-difference-between-square-brackets-and-parentheses-in-a-regex

Comment: I read this http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html. So I was close to find it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the characters just include them in a character class:

```
$string = preg_replace(':[\s!"#$%&\'()*+,-./\\\~]:', '', $string);
```

Or use ASCII hexadecimal for the range and characters:

```
[\x20-\x2f\x5c\x7e]
```

Or use the actual characters in a range as long as you start with the first (space) and end with the last `/` in the range and then add the rest:

```
[ -/\\\~]
```

Comment: `'` should be escaped with ``\``. Also what, if I also want to remove `~`?

Comment: @Legionar Chars that are used as regex delimiters must be escaped inside the pattern.

Comment: @AbraCadaver its not working - `ERROR: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 21` - tested on https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html

Comment: @AbraCadaver I am answering OP top comment.

Comment: Now its ok. Thanks. Also I added there ``\~``, as I edited question.

Comment: "we need 4 \" -- no you don't, since `'[\\\]' === '[\\\\]'` is `true` (the value being `[\\]`).

Comment: @AbraCadaver as I showed above, it doesn't matter; 3 slashes or 4 slashes, the value ends up with 2 slashes.